# Joel Spolsky's profile description is Co-founder & CEO. Should it be updated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog, joel-spolsky, ceo

In the [blog authors](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/page/2/) page, the description of the [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/spolsky/)'s profile is **Co-founder & CEO**.
On [October 1st, 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/24/announcing-stack-overflows-new-ceo-prashanth-chandrasekar/), Prashanth Chandrasekar joined as New CEO.

Is it required to update Joel Spolsky's profile?

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Joel]

Note: As per [Joel Spolsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/4)'s profile page in Meta Stack Exchange, he added the description as ".... and served as CEO of Stack Overflow from 2010-2019".

Comment: The [blog authors](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors) are **terribly outdated**, e.g. Kasra still appear as "Mobile Team Lead". o_O (second page)

Comment: If user profiles weren't outdated, would it really be a blog? I've seen _has just joined the company_ in blog profiles while in fact the user had worked there several years and had already left. No-one ever updates blog user profiles.

Comment: Honest question, seriously, why does it bother you?

Comment: Maybe https://xkcd.com/386/  ?

Comment: The marketing team is auditing profiles of former employees to fix these inaccuracies. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Josh Heyer and Jon Ericson are also still listed as "Community Managers" on the blog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently in the [blog authors page](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/), the description of the Joel Spolsky's profile is updated with the new page design.
Please find the screenshot below:

> [image: Joel Spolsky]

Comment: Well, it's a bit creepy seeing an anonymous avatar, and Spolsky's not alone. There are another 19 anonymous ghost avatars. Hardly the image of friendliness and warm welcomes that a 21st century company ought to transmit. Overall the page is weird, and spooky.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Considering the alternatives it isn't that bad. At least the text is correct now.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't possible to answer this question, as we don't know Joel's priorities.

If he is still around, and if he is looking at MSE, sure, then theoretically he could now update his profile. But whether that profile gets updated or not, that is really not a problem of the MSE community.

And honestly, given the amount of "open questions" from the MSE community towards the SE Inc. leadership, that profile text should be at the very bottom of priorities for their work items.

Or Joel simply wants to avoid updating multiple times, so he waits to decide whether the profile needs to talk about SE Inc. and its wonderful community in past perfect. Because new management running it into the ground you know...

Comment: Re *"if he is looking at MSE"*: Apparently yes - *"[Last seen 2 days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/joel-spolsky)"*